# Javascript equivalet of php move_uploaded_file

Tags: javascript, html

Just want to know if there's a java script code equivalent to PHP's move_uploaded_file function?

Comment: That command only makes sense if run on a server, and plain JavaScript as used in a `<script>` runs on the client, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, javascript does not have the ability to have files uploaded to it or to move them around on a disk.

Javascript is sandboxed, meaning that it cant do anything outside of its running context.

***This is for obvious security reasons...***  mainly  the risk that a malicious site would upload some sort of virus or other malware to your device and then move it somewhere on your device using pure javascript...

This would be bad.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server for file upload, the only thing you can do in javascript is an Ajax upload.

For example something like https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/